# Tutorial / Overview about Prefuse graph layouts?

Tags: prefuse

So far my prefuse visualization uses a RandomLayout, since I couldn't find out how other layouts, e.g. DirectedForceLayout or BallonTreeLayout work exactly.

I googeled a lot, but couldn't find any explanation or tutorial that shows my various prefuse graph layouts and how I should use it.

Is there any tutorial available?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a tutorial, but prefuse comes with a demo of `ForceDirectedLayout`:

https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/demos/prefuse/demos/GraphView.java